# HTTP request from JAVA sends back error 503 on some environments

Tags: java, http, http-status-code-503

I've already checked this SO : [http client head method against a website returns 503 but the site just runs fine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13923618/http-client-head-method-against-a-website-returns-503-but-the-site-just-runs-fin) but it did not really help.

I've a desktop app that is making a HTTP request from JAVA. It works pretty well on most laptops but for some reasons, on some it always returns

```
error 503 - Service unavailable.
```

When I directly pass the same url of the failing request on the same laptop inside a browser, it works fine.

Checking the server logs, I don't see any entry for these 503 errors, which lead me to think that the calls are blocked on laptop-side.

I've tried to profile the request sent with Fiddler, I see it pass then returning 503. I've also tried to check with WireShark but I'm not really used to use it and felt kinda lost.

Any idea about what is happening there? I've tried to turn off proxy, anti-virus, firewall, ... on failing laptops but still nothing, error 503 remains.

Thanks by advance :).

Comment: I would recommend reading the manual on Wireshark and trying to use it again. Without seeing the differences between packets sent by your browser and Java app you will not be able to find the problem. Anyway, I do not think this is a programming-related question, so you'd rather ask it on http://serverfault.com/ or something.

Comment: Hi. Exactly, you saved my day I wasn't able to find the right Stack Exchange for the question. Thanks.