# How to download a file from a URL which redirects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, urllib2

I need to download a file using url-->https://readthedocs.org/projects/django/downloads/pdf/latest/

This url redirects to a url with a .pdf file.

How can I download that file with this url using python ?

I've tried :-

```
import urllib
def download_file(download_url):
    web_file = urllib.urlopen(download_url)
    local_file = open('some_file.pdf', 'w')
    local_file.write(web_file.read())
    web_file.close()
    local_file.close()

if __name__ == 'main':
    download_file('https://readthedocs.org/projects/django/downloads/pdf/latest/')
```

but this is not working

Comment: What have you tried that didn't work ? Don't mean to be harsh but it's so trivial that I fail to understand what your actual problem is...

Comment: I've tried the measures to download a regular file with .pdf extension in the URL

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
import requests
url = 'https://readthedocs.org/projects/django/downloads/pdf/latest/'
r = requests.get(url, allow_redirects=True)  # to get content after redirection
pdf_url = r.url # 'https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/django/latest/django.pdf'
with open('file_name.pdf', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(r.content)
```

If you want to download the file from other method or you want to get only final redirected URL you can use `requests.head()` as shown below:

```
r = requests.head(url, allow_redirects=True)  # to get only final redirect url
```

Comment: @TheGodfather so as it is out of scope for `requests` module.